# How do I debug a published XBAP file in VS2010?

Tags: c#, debugging, xbap

I need to debug a full-trust application either by specifying a URL or, ideally, from within the web app I am intending to deploy it to.  I've tried the following:

- Running "PresentationHost.exe -embedding" from the command-line, attaching through Visual Studio.  The IDE shows that my breakpoints are valid until I actually attempt to load the .xbap file, at which point it shows that there are no symbols loaded.  None of my breakpoints are hit.  I've tried "mage -cc" before doing this per several recommendations elsewhere.
- Hard-coded URL in the project's Debug panel then F5.  Alternatively, "PresentationHost.exe -embedding -debug" and attach to process then load the .xbap in IE.  Both result in the following error when the page appears:

> System.ArgumentException: URI formats are not supported.
>
> ```
>    at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(...)
>    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(...)
>    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(...)
>    at System.Windows.Interop.ApplicationLauncherXappDebug.GetIdFromManifest(...)
>    at System.Windows.Interop.ApplicationLauncherXappDebug.GetApplicationIdentity()
>    at System.Windows.Interop.ApplicationLauncherXappDebug.Initialize()
>    at System.Windows.Interop.DocObjHost.MS.Internal.AppModel.IBrowserHostServices.Run(...)
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it.  The "PresentationHost.exe -embedding" will work, provided that you select the .pdb file to be published, which it is not by default.  This follows from what I saw before, where the debugger appeared to have symbols then not, once the app actually loaded.  To clarify:

- Go into the Publish tab on the project properties
- Click "Application Files..."
- Check "Show all files"
- Select the .pdb file for the executable to be included.
- Republish
- PresentationHost.exe -embedding
- Attach to process or set the project to run this out of the debug tab
- Launch the web page in a browser and navigate to the xbap file, breakpoints should be hit now.

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain what you mean with `PresentationHost.exe -embedding` I have a winform wrapped in the xbap and can attach but cant hit breakpoitns.. .

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to source code and you deploy on localhost you can simply add `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` in your code. This will allow You to attach with VS to any process your XBAP is using.