# IIS related System.ExecutionEngineException

Tags: wpf, winforms, iis-7, xbap

After too many hours of research I have come up with nothing to solve this problem.
I am running a WPF program in an .xbap page file being hosted on internet explorer. Running the project in Visual Studio 2010 works just fine and generates no errors.

I want to be able to host the webpage on IIS 7.0 and to browse to it with a windows forms application. To test this I created a new website on port 80 in IIS manager. I then published the project to the local website folder and added the autogenerated project certificate file (projectName_TemporaryKey.pfx) to my Trusted Publishers and Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

My problem is this: whenever I try to browse to the file with internet explorer or with my windows forms program, the wpf program stops working. When pulling up the just-in-time debugger, I am informed that there is a System.ExecutionEngineException but am given no source code, no stack trace, and no data outside of an empty Dictionary enumerable. My guess is that this might have something to do with the database call made in the program to another machine, but I can't prove that.

I've tried several things to solve this including repairing my .NET 4.0 framework and altering permissions but nothing seems to be affect the error.

Does anyone know of a way to get more information on this error, or perhaps a step I may have missed when publishing this project?

Thanks very much.

Comment: It's the browser of choice of our client. I'd like to test it on firefox as well, but it requires some plugin that I haven't found. I believe there was such a plugin at some point, but it was recalled due to security problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to check:

- Windows event log often includes additional exception information (although usually in an awful format)
- Output some [trace information](https://naveensrinivasan.wordpress.com/2010/03/17/using-clr-4-0-event-tracing-for-windows-etw-along-with-application-etw/) from your application so you can follow what's happening
- Try attaching a debugger to the [WPFHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970051.aspx) and then stepping through the code

Comment: Found my problem by attaching a debugger to WPFHost Presentation.exe with the directions found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688623/how-do-i-debug-a-published-xbap-file-in-vs2010

Thanks!

Turns out some vital files were not copied properly when publishing, something that I will also have to investigate.

Comment: Check that if you added the files outside VS, that you specifically refreshed the folder view then did right-click, Include in project - Then of course, check the build actions - should be copy/compile as appropriate

Comment: The problem wasn't that I missed build actions or something, but that .xml files were, for some reason, not copied by default into the program's AppData. Fixed by setting the publish status to "Include" instead of "Datafile" in Project.properties->Publish tab-> Application Files